# How to do in-file/out-file in VS2013, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, fstream, istream

I am new to C++ Programming, and I initially learned my basics in VS 2010. I upgraded to VS2013, and I tried to declare my `ifstream/ofstream`
variables. It would fail to build my program until I either deleted or commented them out.
The code below is just the header file which I'm defining a class which I intend to inherit and save variables from a parent class (character). All of the following includes are in my CPP.

Thanks to those already answered, I removed the istream, and my namespace was present, but I failed to mentioned that and I apologize for my lack of clarity.
However, the program is still producing the previously noted errors.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <limits>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    class saveLoad : public character 
    { 
        public:     
        saveLoad();     
        void saveGameFunc();    
        void loadGameFunc();

        ifstream loadGame;  
        ofstream saveGame;
     };
```

The Errors I receive are:

> Error 39  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: char const & __thiscall std::_String_const_iterator > >::operator*(void)const "
>   (??D?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@QBEABDXZ) E:\Text
>   Rpg\Text Rpg\Game.obj Text Rpg

and

> Error 40  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   E:\Text Rpg\Debug\Text
>   Rpg.exe   1   1   Text Rpg

Can someone please explain to me the proper way to declare/define in-file and out-file in VS2013?

Comment: This code in its current form is not even a valid C++.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine in Visual Studio 2013 for me after I added an empty character class, provided empty implementations for the 3 functions listed in the saveload class, and added a main function.  This means the error is in the code you did not show us.  Please construct a short complete example of the problem and edit it into the question.

Comment: You might also read the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919836/unresolved-external  It's likely your project is setup incorrectly.

Comment: My Project was setup incorrectly. After Reviewing your recommended thread, My program now compiles. Thank you for help, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't those be `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`?

Unless you have using `std::ifstream` and using `std::ofstream` in that file but didn't post it. Both `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` are within the `<fstream>` header, so you don't actually need the `<istream>` one, unless you're using it for something else.

You also have a compiler error here:

```
ofstream saveGame:
```

Which should be:

```
ofstream saveGame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring namespace
try changing

```
ifstream loadGame;
ofstream saveGame;
```

to

```
std::ifstream loadGame;
std::ofstream saveGame;
```