# Changing Runtime Library broke std::string. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, sdl-2

EDIT:
I've fixed the problem by setting my Runtime Library to inherit from project default.
I was using Multi-treaded DLL(/MT) because a SDL-2 tutorial I used did that.

Can someone explain why this broke the string's of c++?

---

Whenever I try to use a string my compiler gives me the following errors:

> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate(unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)"
>
> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate(unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)"

I've stripped all my code to the bare minimum and it is as followed:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string resPath;
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea where to look. Does anyone have an idea?

I'm using MSVS Community 2015.

Comment: What version of MSVS?

Comment: See if [this answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11919930/5688187).

Comment: If you change the runtime library like that you need to do a full rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem with VS2017.  It turned out that I had my runtime library settings wrong.  I had accidently set it to Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) for the debug configuration.  It should have been Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) or Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).